# Multiple kinect static transform

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, octomap-server, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to use RGBDSlam and Octomap on multiple Kinects. But not simultaneously. I would run one kinect each time. The loop is to slam an area, send the model to octomap server then launch a second camera (and shutting down the first one). The 2nd camera would also do the same thing but I won't restart octomap_server. So it would build up two octomaps after two slams in the server.

I should use a static transform on one kinect. I tried to have two different kinect_frames.launch files feeding to openni_node.launch files, But due to the fact that the cameras are NOT running at the same time, I'm not sure that having one single tf would be the answer for me.

Cameras are mounted back to back.
Any advice would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32441/multiple-kinect-static-transform/) by [Amin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2235/amin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DonaldV](https://answers.ros.org/users/2920/donaldv/) on 2013-08-14**:
Can you please share the launch files if you have solved this problem? I am working on similar stuff but could not figure out how to configure the tf frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would need two different tf frames map->kinect1 and map->kinect2, which you can publish statically. The static transform publishers can run all the time.
Then, configure two launch files for the kinect cameras. One should publish in the kinect1 frame, the other in the kinect2 frame. If they both output to the same topic but with different tf's, octomap_server will lookup the correct tf to the global /map frame.

You can also publish kinect1 directly in the map frame, and publish a static transform map->kinect2 (= kinect1->kinect2). But you definitely need the two kinect frames (whether static or moving while in RGBDSLAM) registered in the global map frame.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VEGETA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26893/vegeta/) on 2016-07-27**:
thanks for the info!

can I use 2 or more Kinects to build and update one map (by any method) using octomap? this is to put 3 kinects to cover one big area to continuously monitor moving objects and identify them as dynamic obstacles.

**Comment by [Engle Hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28707/engle-hsu/) on 2016-12-04**:
Hello! I'm tring the same thing,use mutli-kinects to build and update one map with rgbdslam or rtabslam
if someone have good idea about this.